# Variable keeps staying to one value

Tags: javascript

I have a loop which im trying to make onclicks with their own ID number but it keeps updating to the last number in the loop - im wondering how i can stop it over writing the variable so they keep their own number?

This is what i have:

```
count = 0;
for(i in my_array){ 
    if(my_array[i][2])){ //if the data value is true
        document.getElementById('div_id_'+count).onclick = function()
        {
            alert(i);
        };
    count++;
    }   
}
```

Thing is alert(i) always shows the last value of my_array... so im wondering how i can stop it over writing each time so each div can parse their own value?

Comment: I know ... its a boolean check the array has further array properties.. not really relevant to why variable i gets over written.

Comment: No its not it does what its meant to do. Its position 2 of position i of the array.. its multi dimensional but totally off topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
count = 0;
my_array.forEach(function(i) { 
    if(my_array[i][2])){ //if the data value is true
        document.getElementById('div_id_'+count).onclick = function()
        {
            alert(i);
        };
    count++;
    }
});
```

if my_array is Object instead of Array

```
count = 0;
Object.keys(my_array).forEach(function(i) { 
    if(my_array[i][2])){ //if the data value is true
        document.getElementById('div_id_'+count).onclick = function()
        {
            alert(i);
        };
    count++;
    }
});
```

Comment: Hmm i get this:
Object #<Object> has no method 'forEach'

Comment: How can i display it to check which one it is ?

Comment: Object.prototype.toString.call(my_array)

Answer (score 3):

You are running into an issue with Closure. It is a tricky topic. Check out this url: http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#closure_for_events

Basically the `i` value is evaluated when you click the element; not when you assign the event so at that point `i` is set to the last value in the loop. You need to create a separate function to bind to the click event that takes the `i` parameter. An example:

```
function HandleClick(i){
  return function() { alert(i); };
}

count = 0;
for(i in my_array){ 
    if(my_array[i][2])){ //if the data value is true
        document.getElementById('div_id_'+count).onclick = HandleClick(i);
    count++;
    }   
}
```

Now the `HandleClick` function is creating its own closure for the `i`, and it will be set to the value passed in from the loop.

Comment: So is there a way for it to work dynamically because i will need to do this alot for different functions or will i need a handle click for every function ?

Comment: I think you can just make a copy of i inside your click event and reference that instead.

Comment: I'm not sure i follow what you mean by that. Some where in the script above it will need to pass "count" and "i" from handleclick to the relevant function

Comment: Inside the click function try: var x = i; alert(x).

Answer (score 1):

Stash the value in the element:

```
var count = 0;
for (var i in my_array)
{ 
    if (my_array[i][2])) //if the data value is true
    {
        var el = document.getElementById('div_id_'+count);
        el.setAttribute("my_value", i);
        el.onclick = function()
        {
            alert(this.getAttribute("my_value"));
        };
        count++;
    }   
}
```